# INNER JOIN same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, self-join

I am trying to get some rows from the same table. It's a user table: user has `user_id` and `user_parent_id`.

I need to get the `user_id` row and `user_parent_id` row. I have coded something like this:

```
SELECT user.user_fname, user.user_lname
FROM users as user
INNER JOIN users AS parent
ON parent.user_parent_id = user.user_id
WHERE user.user_id = $_GET[id]
```

But it doesn't show the results. I want to display user record and its parent record.

Comment: Maybe just SELECT * FROM users WHERE (id = 4 OR parent_id = 4) ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `JOIN` condition.

```
SELECT user.user_fname,
       user.user_lname,
       parent.user_fname,
       parent.user_lname
FROM users AS user
JOIN users AS parent 
  ON parent.user_id = user.user_parent_id
WHERE user.user_id = $_GET[id]
```

**Edit**:
You should probably use `LEFT JOIN` if there are users with no parents.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input..
I actually didnt have parent ID set while testing, now its working.. one more thing may be it will help someone, I was saving user_parents as TEXT in the format "1,2" so it means details of 2 users.. so in this scenario my final working query is below:


    $query  = "
    select user.user_fname, user.user_lname, parent.user_lname 
    AS plname, parent.user_fname AS pfname

    from {$prefix}users as user
    join {$prefix}users as parent on parent.user_id  
    IN(user.user_parents)

    where user.user_id =".$id; 

thanks all once again..

Comment: @user1718343 Never ever **EVER** store delimited data like that in columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use UNION like

```
SELECT  user_fname ,
        user_lname
FROM    users 
WHERE   user_id = $_GET[id]
UNION
SELECT  user_fname ,
        user_lname
FROM    users 
WHERE   user_parent_id = $_GET[id]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this should be the select (if I understand the question correctly)

```
select user.user_fname, user.user_lname, parent.user_fname, parent.user_lname
... As before
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should work fine, but you have to use the alias `parent` to show the values of the parent table like this:

```
select 
  CONCAT(user.user_fname, ' ', user.user_lname) AS 'User Name',
  CONCAT(parent.user_fname, ' ', parent.user_lname) AS 'Parent Name'
from users as user
inner join users as parent on parent.user_parent_id = user.user_id
where user.user_id = $_GET[id];
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the table is created but try this...

```
SELECT users1.user_id, users2.user_parent_id
FROM users AS users1
INNER JOIN users AS users2
ON users1.id = users2.id
WHERE users1.user_id = users2.user_parent_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets try to answer this question, with a good and simple scenario, with 3 **`MySQL`** tables i.e. **datetable**, **colortable** and **jointable**.

***first*** see values of `table` **datetable** with `primary key` assigned to `column` **dateid**:

```
mysql> select * from datetable;
+--------+------------+
| dateid | datevalue  |
+--------+------------+
|    101 | 2015-01-01 |
|    102 | 2015-05-01 |
|    103 | 2016-01-01 |
+--------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

now move to our ***second*** `table` values **colortable** with `primary key` assigned to `column` **colorid**:

```
mysql> select * from colortable;
+---------+------------+
| colorid | colorvalue |
+---------+------------+
|      11 | blue       |
|      12 | yellow     |
+---------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and our final ***third*** `table` **jointable** have **no** `primary keys` and values are:

```
mysql> select * from jointable;
+--------+---------+
| dateid | colorid |
+--------+---------+
|    101 |      11 |
|    102 |      12 |
|    101 |      12 |
+--------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Now** our condition is to find the **dateid's**, which have both **color** values *blue* and *yellow*.

So, our query is:

```
mysql> SELECT t1.dateid FROM jointable AS t1 INNER JOIN jointable t2
    -> ON t1.dateid = t2.dateid
    -> WHERE
    -> (t1.colorid IN (SELECT colorid FROM colortable WHERE colorvalue = 'blue'))
    -> AND
    -> (t2.colorid IN (SELECT colorid FROM colortable WHERE colorvalue = 'yellow'));
+--------+
| dateid |
+--------+
|    101 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Hope, this would help many one.