# MySQL Inner Join with condition for the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `activities` which includes activities of different kinds, some of them are related. Each activity of type `A` is matched with an activity of type `B`, for simplicity let's assume there is no missing data. Up to this point the setup is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796738/inner-join-same-table/14796850).

Each activity has a few columns, including `activity_type`, `related_activity_id` and `location_id`. I can query for the pairs very easily:

```
SELECT 
A.location_id as 'A location id',
B.location_id as 'B location id'
FROM (SELECT * FROM activities WHERE `activities`.`activity_type` IN ('Activities::A') AND (`activities`.`related_activity_id` IS NOT NULL)) AS A
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM activities WHERE `activities`.`activity_type` IN ('Activities::B') AND (`activities`.`related_activity_id` IS NOT NULL)) AS B
ON A.related_act_id = B.id;
```

The problem is when I want to find the mismatching pairs, that is the pairs where the location of A does not match the location of B. I have tried using

```
WHERE A_location_id <> B_location_id
```

but then it does not recognize the columns:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'A_location_id' in 'where
> clause'   0.734 sec

Unwillingly, I have converted the where clause to:

```
WHERE A.location_id <> B.location_id
```

But now the query is awfully long and MySQL workbench suffocates and the eventually kills the query:

> Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

I have tried using a longer timeout query, it did not help even by a bit. Any ideas on how to tacke this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HAVING in MySQL

BUT SELECT * is bad From as you don't need all columns

```
    SELECT 
        A.location_id AS 'A location id',
        B.location_id AS 'B location id'
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            activities
        WHERE
            `activities`.`activity_type` IN ('Activities::A')
                AND (`activities`.`related_activity_id` IS NOT NULL)) AS A
            INNER JOIN
        (SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            activities
        WHERE
            `activities`.`activity_type` IN ('Activities::B')
                AND (`activities`.`related_activity_id` IS NOT NULL)) AS B ON A.related_activity_id= B.id
    HAVING A_location_id <> B_location_id;
```

So i would reduce the query to, MySQL has to handle less data

```
SELECT 
    A.location_id AS 'A location id',
    B.location_id AS 'B location id'
FROM
    (SELECT 
        location_id,
        related_activity_id
    FROM
        activities
    WHERE
        `activities`.`activity_type` IN ('Activities::A')
            AND (`activities`.`related_activity_id` IS NOT NULL)) AS A
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        location_id,
        id
    FROM
        activities
    WHERE
        `activities`.`activity_type` IN ('Activities::B')
            AND (`activities`.`related_activity_id` IS NOT NULL)) AS B ON A.related_activity_id = B.id
HAVING A_location_id <> B_location_id;
```

At last if the query takes still to long increase the `wait_timeout`

Comment: YESSSSSS this was the solution! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

for me is not so clear,but maybe you can try like this

```
SELECT 
A.location_id as 'A location id',
B.location_id as 'B location id'
FROM activities c
INNER JOIN activities parent ON parent.activity_type = c.activity_type
WHERE related_activity_id IS NOT NULL AND c.location_id != p.location_id
```